# Amazon Cognito: add custom parameters to authorize URL when using OIDC identity provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, auth0

As stated in the title, I would like to add a custom parameter to the `/authorize` URL to which Cognito redirects when working with a OIDC User Pool Identity Provider (in my case `https://example.xx.auth0.com/authorize`).

I found out you can specify an authorize URL through cloudformation but it cannot contain query parameters.

More details:
Cognito is configured through [Serverless](https://www.serverless.com/) (which uses Cloudformation under the hood):

```yaml
Auth0IdentityProvider:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolIdentityProvider
    Properties:
        UserPoolId:
            Ref: CognitoUserPool
        ProviderType: "OIDC"
        ProviderName: "Auth0"
        ProviderDetails:
            client_id: "xxxx"
            client_secret: "xxxx"
            attributes_request_method: "GET"
            oidc_issuer: "https://xxxx.xx.auth0.com"
            authorize_scopes: "openid profile email"
        AttributeMapping:
            email: "email"
```

When navigating to the Cognito hosted UI and selecting the Auth0 provider it redirects to the `/authorize` Cognito endpoint which in turn redirects to the `/authorize` Auth0 endpoint.

I need to add the `connection` parameter to Auth0's `/authorize` in order to bypass its UI and go straight to the social login but I haven't been able to find a way to do so.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when configuring your Auth0 client you can specify the `connection` parameter and Auth0 will skip its UI for you, but it will only do that if the configured `redirect_uri` does not point to localhost.

```
auth0 = await createAuth0Client({
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
    scope: "openid profile email offline_access",
    connection: "linkedin",
});
```

Comment: where do you setup this code?

Comment: @a.k you should already have it in your frontend code if you're using the [Auth0 SPA JS](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js) library